# Who's stealing my commits?

Tags: git, github

Some of the commits I push to my [GitHub work repo](https://github.com/potentialpark/otac-api/graphs/contributors) are not published under my [GitHub name](https://github.com/ehmicky) but under another GitHub user name called [ich123](https://github.com/ich123). The strange part is that this user has joined four years ago (way before I did) and (according to its profile) has never committed. It is like a "ghost commit robber".

Extra information: my GitHub work repo is under my [company organization account](https://github.com/potentialpark) (that I manage) and I use Travis for Continuous Integration. I work on a dev branch that I merge from time to time to master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ git log | grep Author | sort | uniq
Author: Mickael Hebert <OBSCURED>
Author: ehmicky <OBSCURED>
Author: ehmicky <OBSCURED>
Author: ehmicky <OBSCURED>
Author: me <me@me.com>
```

Unless you are really `me@me.com`, you should not be committing as such.

It seems that ich123 has claimed `me@me.com` as his email address on Github. Might be bogus, not sure if this needs verification.

You should be able to override the email to user mappings in your Github account settings, assigning `me@me.com` to yourself.

Comment: Thanks I guess I messed up while setting my account and switching accounts back and forth. Looks like I cannot claim me@me.com so need to leave those commits to ich123.